# using fputs writing multiple lines to a file

Tags: c

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *datafile, *outputfile;
    char c, *line, *line1, *line2, *key, *search;
    int i=0;
    tree_t *tree;


    if(argc > 4){
        printf("Too many arguments");
        exit(1);
    }

    datafile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    outputfile = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    line = malloc(sizeof(char));
    tree = make_empty_tree();

    while((c=getc(datafile)) != EOF) {
         *(line+i) = c;
         i++;
         line = realloc(line, (i+1)*sizeof(char));
         if(c == ';'){
             *(line+i) = '\0';
             i=0;
             line1 = line;
             line = malloc(sizeof(char));       
         } else if(c=='\n') {
             line2 = line;
             tree = insert_tree(tree, line1, line2);
             i=0;
             line = malloc(sizeof(char));

         }

    }


    /*traverse_tree(tree);*/
    i=0;
    key = malloc(sizeof(char));
    while((c = getchar())!=EOF){
        *(key+i) = c;
        i++;
        key = realloc(key, (i+1)*sizeof(char));
        if(c == ';') {
            *(key+i) = '\0';
            i=0;
            search = search_tree(tree, key);
            fputs(search, outputfile); 

        }
    }  


    fclose(datafile);
    fclose(outputfile);


    return 0;
}
```

in the second while loop 
the search_tree function searches argument "key" inside a tree
and outputs the searched result to pointer variable search
then write into file using fputs

the thing is i want to be able to write multiple search results to file
but everytime fputs run it erases the previous search result and writes a new one

how can i store all the search results??

Comment: How did you declare `c` ? `realloc`ating every byte is very in efficient. Where do you `fopen` the file ? Show more code.

Comment: `c` must be declared as an `int`; otherwise `while ((c=getc()) != EOF)` is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: this line: `printf("Too many arguments");` is useless to the use (and me) because it does not indicate how the application should be started from the command line.   suggest something  more like: `printf( "USAGE: %s <firstarg> <secondarg> .... \n", argv[0])'`

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() and family of functions to assure the operation was successful   The expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1 and has absolutely not effect on the parameter passed to malloc/realloc.  It also clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression from the parameter passed to realloc()

Comment: the posted code: 1)  missing prototypes for called functions  2) missing the #include statements for the header files  3) does not pass all those malloc'd memory areas to free() before exiting the program.

Comment: fputs() always advances the 'file pointer'  so it will (without a fseek() or rewind()) never overwrite the previously written contents of the file.   Suggest using a debugger, like gdb, to step through the code to see what is really happening.   Of course, if the application is re-run, the "w" mode of opening the output file will cause the file to be truncated back to zero length.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid that the file is overwritten each time the program is run, then you have to open the file in "append" mode:

```
outputfile = fopen(argv[2], "a" );
```

Moreover:

- it is always better to check for fopen success, even in test/example code (otherwise you will have undefined behavior for accessing null pointer).
- as pointed out by Michael Walz, `realloc`'ating one char at time is very inefficient.
- realloc may fail, you have to check for its resulting being not NULL before assigning it to the same pointer, otherwise there is a memory leak.